# how to submit multiple forms with single submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have multiple forms on the same page but I want to submit all forms together once instead of submitting one at a time. My approach is to clone all the data inside a another form and submit at once but its kind of overhead . So, is there a another approach to submit multiple form data once.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and submit the form [behind the scenes](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)?

Comment: i will do it with AJAX, cause on the submit of one you have to recolect all data of the others forms and create hiddens inputs for the submit..

Comment: I agree with @richardneililagan.  Why have multiple forms instead of just one?  You can always combine all of the separate handlers into a single file, or submit to an overall handler that just `includes` the appropriate files.

Comment: in future that page may contain 2 more form ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will submit all form elements via ajax when `'button'` is clicked

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $.post(this.action, $form.serialize());
    });
});
```

Note that this will not refresh the page, as they are all submitted via ajax...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm. This might sound drastic, but why not encapsulate all the `INPUT`s into just one `FORM` element? If not that, I think you'll have to rely on AJAX to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it the way that your doing it, or you can submit the forms via ajax requests. If there is no need for it to be asynchronous, I would probably do it the way you plan on doing it.