# single javascript function for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that loads different forms depending on user choice. I want to have a single javascript that can read all elements on any of these forms. I don't want to have multiple scripts ... I want a a function, say for example, named `submit([don't know if it should have parameters])`, then when any of the forms is submitted, this function is called and executed. I will be setting the submit action. But I need the function that can read any form.

Comment: Possible duplicate 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681583/how-to-submit-multiple-forms-with-single-submit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057833/jquery-submit-multiple-forms-through-single-reqest-without-ajax

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri Those are are not valid replacements. The OP doesn't want to submit multiple forms at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
document.onsubmit = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submit( ... );        
};
```

So, you cancel any submit actions on the document-level, and then do your own thing using `submit()`...

Use the [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms) collection to access your forms. Use the [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) collection to access the elements of each form.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for ... I want the function to be able to get all the form elements then I'll do whatever the operation is with the form elements.

Comment: @Sikas You want `document.forms` and then `form.elements`. I've updated my answer...

Comment: I found a workaround using `document.forms[0].elements.length` ... Thanks :)