# Two separate forms one submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms that I'd like to be **both** submitted with a **single** submit button. For this particular application I can't just combine them into one form. I've seen posts on this before but haven't yet found a straight-forward answer. How do I modify my html code or php code appropriately to get it to work?  Thanks!

Basically, here's what I'm trying to combine:

```
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php" id='form1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="blue_color">Blue<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<form method="POST" action="mailer.php" id='form2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="red_color">Red<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here's mailer.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "someone@someone.com"; 
    $subject = "Form Example";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $option = $_POST['radio'];
    $dropdown = $_POST['drop_down'];

    foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
        $check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
    }

    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n $check_msg Option: $option\n Drop-Down: $dropdown\n Message:\n $message\n";

    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);

} else {
    echo "blarg!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to submit both of them.

Comment: Once you submit 1, the page reloads. I doubt there's a trivial way to accomplish this.

Comment: `For this particular application I can't just combine them into one form` - why not? You want all the data in your post back, so it seems like good application design to have all the data in one form.

Comment: Please tell everyone why you can't unite the forms into one. I find this very dubious.

Comment: I think you can only submit one form.  However, you may be able to use javascript to combine the values to get and then submit your values that way (via AJAX maybe) and then have your submit button trigger that whole process.  The obvious solution is to combine into a single form though.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681583/how-to-submit-multiple-forms-with-single-submit

Comment: You can make two ajax calls, and then when both are complete submit it for real. However, I find that horrible in comparison to one good structure of the code. Please answer to Seva Alekseyev and scrowler

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - I'm using a liteAccordion http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion and would like a form on each page. On the last page I'd like to put a submit button that compiles the results in each of the accordion pages and submits them into one form, then emails that to me.

Comment: So what keeps you from placing the `<form>` outside of the accordion? Normally, all the sections of the accordion are a part of the same HTML page, despite what the user might think. It's all smoke, mirrors, and dynamic visibility.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - Would I be able to split the form up within different list items? How would I deal with that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a form that spans multiple list items. So there will be a lot of controls, that's fine. You only want to split controls into different forms if you want to submit them separately and/or to different destinations - but you don't. Form is not a visual element - it's just a way to group input controls together.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev  - Genius! It worked! I wouldn't have thought it would allow spanning multiple list items but it does. Thank you for a simple solution!

Comment: I'll make an answer for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what keeps you from placing the `<form>...</form>` outside of the accordion? Normally, all the sections of the accordion are a part of the same HTML page, despite what the user might think. It's all smoke, mirrors, and dynamic visibility.

There's nothing wrong with a form that spans multiple list items. So there will be a lot of controls, that's fine. You only want to split controls into different forms if you want to submit them separately and/or to different destinations - but you don't. Form is not a visual element - it's just a way to group input controls together.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you would need to use ajax (jQuery is easiest) to do it so the page doesn't un-load...

Here's an example to get you started:

http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/