# Submit multiple forms of same page simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

i tried to submit two forms simultaneously, with one POST for creation, another POST for uploading file.

It seems there is always delay in between the two form submission. Is that possible to have them run simultaneously, (different action URLs)?

Comment: How are you determining that one is called before the other? I would expect the file upload to be much slower due to the increased amount of data. If you need to execute some code when both calls have completed, use `$.when`.

Comment: I think you looking something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681583/how-to-submit-multiple-forms-with-single-submit